# Limit number of business connector users in AX2009

Tags: web-services, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, ax, business-connector

**Background**

We provide some webservices to export and import some data to a website. Unfortunatly the programmers of that website don't seem to, or don't want to understand, that if they try three times and get three errors, the 1,000,000th time it also will give an error.

So they constantly open new requests to the webservice wich result in a constant flow of new business connector users. The problem with this is that they creating database blocks, but the database will not be able to solve this because when it will time out, there are a few 1000 new business connector users waiting to block that process all over again. This morning the whole server was inresponsive and a reboot of the AOS toke about 32 minutes to complete. (normally it would take 2 minutes)

**Question**

I was searching for a way to limit the number of business connector users. The only related post I found was this one: 
http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.axapta.programming/2010-01/00045/RE-.NET-business-connector-amp-Web-Services.html

Unfortunatly there is no answer to their question and I couldn't find more topics.. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appriciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the problem is with the web service. Can you rework it so that it does not cause blocking?

Meanwhile, look into the MaxConcurrenctBCSessions setting.
see
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569637(v=ax.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569637%28v=ax.10%29.aspx)

Comment: The problem is probatly in the way the clients use the service; they don't analyse the response.
However, the link you provided seems very usefull. I'll test it on friday and give proper response here. Thanks!

Comment: From personal experience, change the things you know you can control :-)

Comment: Hm, that probably won't work I'm afraid. From the document; "The default value is 100". So if the default is 100, how can I have tens of thousands logged on Business Connector users? :(

Comment: That could be wrong, the default is also documented as  65535. It makes no sense that the default is less than that for web sessions (MaxConcurrentWebSessions). see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569628(v=ax.10).aspx